# Tool / Suggestion o access for server logs

Tags: system-monitoring

I want to publish the previous 3 days of log files in /var/log/msg at CentOS.

Comment: We don't do product or service recommendations.

Comment: I usually use ELK stack but I was looking if there are wiser sysads.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! **Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations** are considered [**off-topic**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com. Potentially your question can be reworded or made suitable for the  [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange community, but before posting, please read their guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like [logstash](http://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) is probably what you are looking for.